# Vue.js: Data binding with object in grand parent component with nested setter method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component structure like this:

`Grandparent` > `Parent` > `Child`

In `Grandparent`, I have a rather complex object, that is being created by a third party library.

I'm trying to bind properties of this object to form input fields in the `Child` component.
Additionally, I need to use a setter method, that is nested in the same object.
Getters and setters should be reactive.

Currently, I'm passing the relevant property and method of the object from `Grandparent` to `Child` as props.
I bind the property with v-model to the input and invoke the method on-change.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, because I don't know if the v-model setter and on-change method both get invoked.

Code:

**Grandparent**:

```
<template>
  <Parent
    :position="complexObject.position"
    :setPosition="complexObject.setPosition"
  ></Parent>
</template>

this.complexObject.position = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 0
}
this.complexObject.setPosition = function(vectorPosition) {
  // ...
}
```

**Parent** component just passes these props further down to `Child`, so I omit the code here.

**Child**

```
<template>
  <b-form-input type="number" v-model.number="position.x" @change="setPosition($event)"></b-form-input>

  <b-form-input type="number" v-model.number="position.y" @change="setPosition($event)"></b-form-input>

  <b-form-input type="number" v-model.number="position.z" @change="setPosition($event)"></b-form-input>
</template>

props: {
  position: Object,
  setPosition: Function
}
```

Is there any better approach to this?
Cheers

Comment: You should bind the form fields to a local object inside Child and initialize this object from the prop. You should also have a deep watcher on the prop - in order to update your local object in Child when the prop changes. When you are finished with form editing - your Child should emit an event to the Grandparent with the new form values and the Grandparent should update the object using its setter - then the new object will be automatically propagated down to Child.

Comment: It works. Thank you!